# How to make stacked listview with animation like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

how do we make a horizontal list like this with an image on the left behind it, then the image slowly disappears when the list is scrolled to the right.

Like this for example

https://imgur.com/nNIaw8Q

I've tried to make a listview in the stack for the image, but I'm confused about how to make the image behind it disappear when the listview is scrolled to the right

Answer (score 0):

You can add listeners to your `ScrollController`. That way you can check the scroll offset and wrapt your background image in an `Opacity` widget.

Here is an implementation example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BackgroundListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const BackgroundListView({super.key});

  @override
  _BackgroundListViewState createState() => _BackgroundListViewState();
}

class _BackgroundListViewState extends State<BackgroundListView> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  double opacity = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        final value = (100 - _scrollController.offset) / 100;
        opacity = value <= 0
            ? 0
            : value >= 1
                ? 1
                : value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/background_image.png',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 200.0),
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return CardComponent();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CardComponent extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardComponent({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60),
        width: 200.0,
        child: Card(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Card Item'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```